# D3 force directed graph with drag and drop support to make selected node position fixed when dropped

Tags: d3.js, drag-and-drop, force-layout

Example on a force direct graph can be found here: http://bl.ocks.org/950642

How can I easily add support for drag and drop?
It should set the node to fixed with current location of where it dropped it.
It is important that rest of the nodes still uses the 'force directed mode' to position rest of the nodes in the graph automatically

https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Force-Layout

I've played around a bit without success, and wondering if anyone is able to give me a quick example on how to add such support as explained above.

Comment: Please post what you have so far

Comment: If it would be nearly close to something working at all, I would gladly post it. But it's better to use the example given as base, as that is the closest I've got so far, aka nothing. Anyhow, I've been thinking on the whole problem yesterday, and working on some ideas. I'll post updates when I get any progress

Comment: Idea: modify the original force.drag function to not fiddle with fixed status at all on mouseover/mouseout

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Finally got it working after figuring out it is not ideal to fight with two "drag" listeners (your own, and force.drag) attached to the nodes!

Much better to only have your own "drag"-listener and call tick() manually which is the key feature of getting the force graph to position the nodes for you on every new node position on the node your dragging.

Working example: http://bl.ocks.org/2883411

Comment: It doesn't render properly in FF. The node to drag does not appear. In Chrome, the image at the node is for a broken image link.

Comment: @Spaceghost : Updated the svg image to use github's favicon now. Works fine in Chrome. When it comes to FF I found it to have bad performance compared to Chrome for these graphs as the force layout algorithm is quite resource hungry. (tested with iceweasel version 10.0.12 (debian's version of firefox in debian). But it stutters at this one too: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1129492 , so I blame FF. Maybe it works better in a newer version?

Comment: FYI, on my Macbook Pro with current version of FF and Chrome, Chrome looks the nicest.  FF looks stuttery.

Comment: How can you re-enable forces on each node after you set it to false? e.g. this line d.fixed = true; in dragend(...) will no longer repel other nodes placed on top.