# Dragging on force layout prevents other mouseup listeners

Tags: d3.js, mouseevent, drag, force-layout, mouseup

I want to enable dragging in a d3.js force layout. When dragging a circle and release the mouse button, I want to call a specific function via callback, like this:

```
this.force = d3.layout.force()
    .nodes(this.nodes)
    .size([this.width, this.height]);

// enable dragging
this.circle
    .call(this.force.drag)
    .on("dragend", function() {
        console.log("You should see this, when releasing a circle.");
    })
    .on("mouseup.drag",function(d,i) {
        console.log("Or see this.");
    });
```

Unfortunately the event is never fired/consumed completely by the force.drag handler.
So how can I execute a given callback function in a d3 force layout at the end of a drag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not calling the `"dragend"` event on `this.force.drag` here.
This also depends on how you have defined `this.force.drag`.

This should work for you

```
myCustomDrag = d3.behavior.drag()
    .on("dragstart", function(d,i){
        //do something when drag has just started
    })
    .on("drag", function(d,i){
        //do something while dragging
    })
    .on("dragend", function(d,i){
        //do something just after drag has ended
    });
```

In the above code, just use `call(myCustomDrag)` on an element (circle here) on which you want this drag behaviour to be present.

Comment: `this.force.drag` is coming from the d3 library, it is not user defined. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11867374/295686) gets close, but I can't get it to work which is why I kept looking.

Comment: Yes it comes from the d3 library, but you can always override it.
The answer you are refering to is just another way of writing the above code.

Comment: I ended up doing more or less what you have here. +1

Comment: Get rid of the semicolons after each of the `on`s -- they will prevent method chaining.