# Suppress mouseover during click and drag in d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a certain behavior in a d3 visualization that occurs on mouseover. It's a [force layout](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Force-Layout), with elements that can be clicked and dragged. Right now if I mouseover one element while dragging another, the mouseover behavior is triggered. I want to suppress that while dragging. How can I make the behavior on one event conditional on the status of another event?

The code right now looks something like:

```
selection
  .call(force.drag) // allows you to drag and drop elements of the force layout
  .on("mouseover", function() {
    // behavior I want to suppress during click and drag
  })
  .on("mouseout", function() {
    // return layout to pre-mouseover state
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the problem is related to this behavior of the force layout: [Dragging on force layout prevents other mouseup listeners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14398724/dragging-on-force-layout-prevents-other-mouseup-listeners)