# Stop Force Layout on d3js and start free dragging nodes

Tags: d3.js, force-layout

I'm using the force layout to represent a directed unweighted network. My inspiration comes from the following example: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1153292

[image]

Since my own data are really a mess, I'd like to stop the layout and move nodes by dragging them manually. I'd also like that the movement of a node doesn't change the position of others. And it's necessary that links become longer, to reach the node which has been moved.

Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: You can call `force.stop()` to stop the simulation.

Comment: Then the movement of the nodes should stop.

Comment: My problem is that when I drag a node it starts again...let's say I would it stop forever...

Comment: Unfortunately you can't disable this. You could however add a custom drag behaviour instead of calling `force.drag`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At the end I found this related question which implements a solution which I'll adopt.

[D3 force directed graph with drag and drop support to make selected node position fixed when dropped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10899725/d3-js-force-directed-graph-with-support-for-drag-and-drop-to-make-selected-node?rq=1)

http://bl.ocks.org/norrs/2883411

Comment: Better than a stop/start button! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

```
function nameOfFunction () {
    d3.selectAll(".classOfYourNodes").each(
        function(d) {
            d.fixed = true;
        }
    )
}
```

The method .each calls the anonymous function, which in this case sets the "fixed" attribute to true for every node within the selection.

Edit: The above is in regards to your comment about wanting to stop all of the nodes and **not** have the force simulation continue when you drag a node, as calling force.stop() does.