# D3js drag behavior with nodes and links

Tags: javascript, d3.js

my final goal is to get something similar to [this](http://jsbin.com/gist/57e7cc43342193d9d21a?js,output). Therefore I'm using d3js, but I'm a very beginner. I tried a lot with the force layout, but I think I don't need any animation only that I can drag nodes which update the links. I already define a drag behavior that works:

```
var dragListener = d3.behavior.drag()
    .on("dragstart", function (d) {
        dragStarted = true;
        d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation();
    })
    .on("drag", function (d) {
        // update the node position
        var n = d3.select(this);
        n.attr("cx", d.x = d3.event.x);
        n.attr("cy", d.y = d3.event.y);
        update();
    })
    .on("dragend", function (d) {});
```

My update method is:

```
function update () {
    force.nodes(nodes)
         .links(links);

    // Update links
    var l = vis.select("#linkG").selectAll("line.link")
               .data(links, function (d) { return d.source.id + "-" + d.target.id; })
               .enter()
               .append("svg:line")
               .attr("class", "link");

    l.style("stroke", "#000")
     .style("stroke-width", 1);

    // Update nodes
    var n = vis.select("#nodeG").selectAll("a")
               .data (nodes, function (d) { return d.id; })
               .enter()
               .append("svg:a").attr("xlink:href", function (d) { return "/user/" + d.id; })
               .append("svg:circle")
               .attr("class", "node")
               .attr("r", function (d) { return d.r; })
               .style("fill", "#454545")
               .style("stroke", "#e7ecef")
               .style("stroke-width", 3)
               .call(dragListener);

    force.on("tick", function () {
        nodes[0].x = WIDTH / 2;
        nodes[0].y = HEIGHT / 2;

        // Tried to update the link positions
        l.attr("x1", function (d) { console.log(d); return d.source.x; }) // HERE
         .attr("y1", function (d) { return d.source.y; })
         .attr("x2", function (d) { return d.target.x; })
         .attr("y2", function (d) { return d.target.y; });

        // Hopefully updates the node positions
        n.attr("cx", function (d) { console.log(d.x); return d.x; })
         .attr("cy", function (d) { return d.y; });
    });
}
```

I have started the force layout at the initialization. The statement `console.log(d)` is never triggered. The data is all fine, in the html all the elements are created fine.

[image]

The problem is, the link is not displayed or updated. Can someone help me to get the correct behavior?

Comment: Extremely ambitious for a beginner! :)

Comment: Well I try it almost the entire 3 days.

Comment: I take my hat off to you! Are you able to put a break point on `return d.x;` just after the console.log ?

Comment: Thanks! I use sublime text, I don't know how I can set a break point but with the console logs I see that in the drag method the `d.x` is correct and the `console.log` in the `force.on tick..` is never called.

Comment: you can put a break point on the line in chrome f12 scripts tab.. So when you run it in the browser you will hit it  (SHOULD hit it) `return d.source.x;`

Comment: Give me a moment. Therefore I have to install Chrome :). The funny thing is that I already implemented a update link method by my own but there I couldn't get a `tick` method.

Comment: I have tried it with the breakpoint and the applications stops in the `force.on tick` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I have the solution (hopefully). A good help was these stack overflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16568861/stop-force-layout-on-d3js-and-start-free-dragging-nodes). Now I can drag the nodes correctly as I want. The point was the `d.fixed = true` for the force layout. Maybe that helps others.